# Angular2 + Rails: Processing by ... as */*

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, xmlhttprequest, angular, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to send the following request from my Angular2 app:

```
getUsers() {
    return this.http.get(this._usersUrl)
        .map(res => <User[]> res.json().data)
        .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

Rails server console says:

```
Started GET "/messages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-13 12:32:39 +0300
Processing by MessagesController#show as */*
Completed 204 No Content in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The question is how do I set `Content-type` to my `get` request?

Comment: what you return show method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used path `/messages`. Instead, you should use `/messages.json`